# Is it possible to turn unification errors into goals in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I've been working on a formalization for a process calculus in Coq ([repository here](https://github.com/takanuva/cps)), and constantly find myself trying to apply a function which fails because of equivalent, but syntactically different, subterms. This often happens because of manipulation of [de Bruijn variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index). As unification fails, I'll usually just replace misbehaving subterms explictly beforehand and then apply the function I need. A simple code as an example of what I mean:

```
Require Import Lia.

Goal
  forall P: nat -> Prop,
  (forall a b c, P (a + (b + c))) ->
  forall a b c, P (b + c + a).
Proof.
  intros.
  (* Unification fails here. *)
  Fail apply H.
  (* Replace misbehaving subterms explictly. *)
  replace (b + c + a) with (a + (b + c)).
  - (* Now application succeeds. *)
    apply H.
  - (* Show now they were the same thing. *)
    lia.
Qed.
```

So, my question is: is there a tactic, or is it possible to write one with ltac, which is similar to apply, but turning unification errors into additional equality goals instead of failing?

Comment: Is `applys_eq` from Programming Language Foundations's LibTactics (https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/LibTactics.html) along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoriaReinstateCMs, that's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! I've turned it into an answer (tbh it was my bad for trying to answer in a comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`applys_eq` from *Programming Language Foundations*' [LibTactics](http://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/LibTactics.html) will accomplish that. From the documentation (as of Version 6.1 of the book):

> `applys_eq H` helps proving a goal of the form `P x1 .. xN` from an [sic] hypothesis `H` that concludes `P y1 .. yN`, where the arguments `xi` and `yi` may or may not be convertible. Equalities are produced for all arguments that don't unify.
>
> The tactic invokes `equates` on all arguments, then calls `applys K`, and attempts reflexivity on the side equalities.